# Class contains 1 abstract method

Tags: magento2, php, module

During the install module we get issue:

```
Compilation was started.
Proxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 34.0                                                                                                              Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 36.0                                                                                                              Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec                                                                                                              36.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Class Dotpay\Payment\Helper\Data\Notification contains                                                                                                              1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the rema                                                                                                             ining methods (Dotpay\Provider\NotificationProviderInterface::getCreditCard) in                                                                                                              /home/czasowe/domains/gerris.pl/public_html/vendor/dotpay/magento2-payment/Helpe                                                                                                             r/Data/Notification.php on line 27
```

> Fatal error: Class Dotpay\Payment\Helper\Data\Notification contains 1 abstract m                                                                                                             ethod and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods                                                                                                              (Dotpay\Provider\NotificationProviderInterface::getCreditCard) in /home/czasowe                                                                                                             /domains/gerris.pl/public_html/vendor/dotpay/magento2-payment/Helper/Data/Notifi                                                                                                             cation.php on line 27

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the class `Dotpay\Payment\Helper\Data\Notification` is trying to instantiate an abstract method, which may not be instantiated.

You could change this module to extend instead of instantiating the abstracted class.

Reference in the [PHP Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).